# How to create factory function for generic class without duplicating signature

Tags: typescript

Example code:

```
interface ValueGenerator {
    next(): any;
}

class NumberGenerator {
    next(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}

class ArrayGenerator<T extends ValueGenerator> {

    private generator: T;
    constructor(valueGenerator: T) {
        this.generator = valueGenerator;
    }

    next(): Array<ReturnType<T['next']>> {
        return [this.generator.next()];
    }
}

const numGenerator = new NumberGenerator();
const fn1 = <T extends ValueGenerator>(t: T) => new ArrayGenerator(t);
const fn2 = (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof ArrayGenerator>) => new ArrayGenerator(...args)
const generator1 = fn1(numGenerator);
const generator2 = fn2(numGenerator);

// number[]
const a = generator1.next();
// any[]
const b = generator2.next();
```

Is there a way to create factory function for `ArrayGenerator` without manually writing the correct signature like I did with `fn1`? Ideally I'd like to do something like `fn2`, but it doesn't work as intended. `fn2` will infer the constructor parameters correctly, but doesn't infer `generator2.next` return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually write out a function I don't think the compiler will ever infer a generic function for you.  However, TypeScript 3.4 introduced [support for higher order type inference in generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) and TypeScript 3.5 followed up with [the corresponding support for generic constructor functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-constructors).  This allows you to write a generic higher order function that takes a function and returns a function, and the compiler will try to automatically make the output generic if the input was generic. The inference algorithm isn't perfect, but it's good enough for what I want to do here, which is to make a generic "constructor-to-factory" function:

```
function ctorToFactory<A extends any[], R>(ctor: new (...args: A) => R): (...args: A) => R {
    return (...args) => new ctor(...args);
}
```

If you call that on `ArrayGenerator`, you get a generic `fn2` automatically without having to type it yourself:

```
const fn2 = ctorToFactory(ArrayGenerator);
// const fn2: <T extends ValueGenerator>(valueGenerator: T) => ArrayGenerator<T>
const generator2 = fn2(numGenerator);
const b = generator2.next(); // number[]
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIHEIjRxgD2UyA3gLABQy9yhAHmABQCUAXMnCAJ4BuWgF9atBBjgBnKcgByWALYAjaPkJRiZSrQaMILDtxBLV5anT0MoEMFighkARiGX6omh-GSZyAIJQmnzqRKRQADwAKsgGkCAAJrLo2HgEoWQAfDo0ugwADlDAAG7EKADmaZph3JGueggkIFJgUFgIYawlKSFVZDXs2VYMYAAWwFIAdBUaWuQAvMhdOD2zdQxebvqGXP6BcHzhAEq29iCRfHkQUQDaAOTMYLcAuhlZFkP0NnYOyNej41NKrMJg8OE81u4RGIaA0mmBGEoVmFkAtCAB3eSmNRAjrsVyw5rIGAgJwo5BRGIsAiJNCYZY4zKsMD9FFZdG7IJIshMvHiRqE6bpKCkhbEpysEyKLlQXkw-nwuBkwW9YUg2IcATIAD0WoRKmg1ye0NoMCwIHawEayHaZEiJAAYogwgc-JS4jTeHxDQAaZCHDKsG1QYwQDGsCYRuBQMpSbh+AZzLKHHbhyPR2P+BNJwbWE4-VMTKMxrP6DFBgtFqSyjwE+HEgBMZKDdsdQb4rACnIZMtcOut8qJIHr3ApsWpSTpqRmYQDSynQpZiY5+2lUQyfLhyGVs0boqHEsR3dlteQyiV3frau2mr7krMhqAA)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I thought it would be easier if I manually write the function as it'd be one "hoop" less. This is even better. Thanks a lot!